# How to know WIFI connection progress in OpenWRT?

Tags: linux, wifi-configuration, openwrt

As the description in title. How to obtain the connection progress in OpenWRT programmatically, for example, trying to connect to the wifi, obtaining IP address. Is there a ubus ipc that I can connect to in order to get these progress?

Thanks.

Comment: Is openwrt acting as server or client?

Comment: @davidgo it act as a client